# Using tc rate limit all traffic except from one IP

Tags: tc

Currently i have the below rule for rate limiting the traffic on port 22. This applies for all traffic, however i don't want this to apply for one IP say x.x.x.x , how to do this? So if the traffic is from x.x.x.x and port 22, there should not be any rate limitation.

```
        tc filter add dev eth1 parent ffff: protocol ip u32 \
              match ip sport 22 0xffff  \
              police rate 800kbit burst 24000 drop flowid :1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter that will match this IP with an empty [action](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-actions.8#ACTION_OPTIONS) that will classify the packet as "pass", without going through further filters. Since without specifying a priority the order can't be guessed, both filters should have a *priority* (aka *prio* or *pref*) set. So if you want to spare the IP 192.0.2.10 from rate limitation, you can replace your filter with those two:

```
tc filter add dev eth1 parent ffff: protocol ip priority 1 \
   u32 match ip src 192.0.2.10 action pass
tc filter add dev eth1 parent ffff: protocol ip priority 2 \
   u32 match ip sport 22 0xffff action police rate 800kbit burst 24000 drop flowid :1
```

Note that [police](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-police.8) is also an action, but the action keyword is optional (while it has to be stated for an empty action with only a *pass* option).

Also, if it can still suit this case, you should consider using shaping (delaying before having to drop) on egress traffic, rather than policing (dropping only) on ingress traffic: this would probably improve performances (avoiding duplicate packets on the wire because of drops).